# Oracle provider for TORA application on Ubuntu 16.04 (desktop)

Tags: oracle, ubuntu, tora

I installed tora (v 2.1.3) on ubuntu 16.04 (desktop), after opening the software says: there's no connection provider

I need to connect it to a Oracle database.

More information:
I installed Oracle Clients (for Oracle v 11.2.0.3.0.1)

1. Instant Client Package - Basic
2. Instant Client Package - SQL*Plus: Additional libraries and executable for running SQL*Plus with Instant Client
3. Instant Client Package - ODBC: Additional libraries for enabling ODBC applications

I connected to Oracle database on enother server by TNS with SQLPLUS.
I connected to MySQL database with tora, but I can't install provider for oracle.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

This version of tora is not supported anymore. Moreover the version shipped with Ubuntu possibly does not support Oracle at all. Try to download fresh version from SourceForge. (or compile it from sources)